# What spider is this?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, poison

I found this spider in my flat in Berlin, Germany. It looks like a [Cheiracanthium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheiracanthium), but which species? [Mildei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheiracanthium_mildei)? Or is it a different spider?

The body is approx. 8-9mm long and it lost 4 legs when I tried to catch it unfortunately.

[image: Spider-1]
[image: Spider-2]
[image: Spider-3]

Comment: I'm not an expert.It seems to be a male Cheiracanthium mildei.

Comment: ghost spider,miturgidae ?? Spiders are really a pain to identify